# How to set filter in the log4j.xml

Tags: logging, log4j, java.util.logging

HI,

In our web application it prints all the logs are printed like Spring and JSF jars files. Which not required for us. How can I set in the log4j.xml file to filter only for our application?

**Updated**

The following is the configuration we are using for the logging. Can you please tell me whether it is correct? Where I have to add the logger element in the file?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<!-- Log4j Configuration file to log the messages into different logfiles -->
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:/logs/DEBUGFILE.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="true"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
     <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="INFO" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:/logs/AUDIT_TRAIL.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ERROR" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:/logs/ERRORFILE.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FATEL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:/logs/FATELFILE.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="FATAL" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FATEL"/>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log only warning for Spring :

```
<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="warn"/>
    <appender-ref ref="socket"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</logger>
```

Same for JSF with the jsf package name...
`javax.faces`, `org.apache.myfaces`, `com.sun.faces` etc... also, the appender-ref refers to your appenders...

Comment: Between the last appender and the root tag. Also make sure to update the appender-ref with your own appender names.

Comment: can you send the non-xml format as well?
is it like:
log4j.logger.org.springframework=warn

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the own logger and appender for your application.
For example, if you need to log the trace message in `com.xyz.http.RequestFilter`:

```
log4j.com.xyz.http.RequestFilter=TRACE, TRACE_APPEND

log4j.appender.TRACE_APPEND=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPEND.File=example.log

log4j.appender.TRACE_APPEND.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPEND.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.TRACE_APPEND.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPEND.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

See more at log4j official manual http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: Using properties files are not encouraged anymore.

Comment: Especially not when the OP asked about `log4j.xml`.