# Logging error to stderr and debug, info to stdout with log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to add logging to an application I am developing, using apache log4j. At this point I want to redirect all log messages for level INFO and lower (TRACE, DEBUG) to stdout and all other log messages from WARN and above (ERROR, FATAL) to stderr.
For example:

```java
...
logger.info("Processing at some point"); // must be written to stdout
logger.debug("Point x was processed"); // must be written to stdout
logger.warn("Incorrect point config"); // must be written only to stderr
logger.error("Exception occurred at point x"); // must be written only to stderr
```

So what should be my log4j.properties file? Here how it looks at this momment:

```sh
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, stderr

# configure stdout
# set the conversion pattern of stdout
# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.Target   = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n

# configure stderr
# set the conversion pattern of stdout
# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold = WARN
log4j.appender.stderr.Target   = System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n
```

The problem with the above configuration is that the logger.error() ... is printed at stdout too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per Jon Skeet's previous post at [Post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/200110.mbox/%3COF31CC3305.157ED9C1-ON85256ADB.005E5C35@ma.lycos.com%3E)

> unfortunately there is no *maximum* threshold, so wherever you get
>   debug messages, you also get warning messages. That's a bit of a pain,
>   IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Is there any way to subclass the appender (for example stdout appender) so when a log above INFO will be rejected? What about filters: setting up a filter for stdout so to accept only logs of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO?

Comment: Absolutely. You can create your own appender and point to it in the configuration file.

Comment: Here is an example of (in xml config) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825072/how-to-set-filter-in-the-log4j-xml so is this same as: log4j.appender.stdout.Filter = org.apache.varia.LevelRangeFilter log4j.appender.stdout.Filter.LevelMax = INFO log4j.appender.stdout.Filter.LevelMin = TRACE? If so it doesn't seem to work in my case. A warning message is thrown by log4j which tell the filter can not be set...

Answer (score 54):

Solved below also in properties file format. The trick was to get the filter definition right. [Log4j properties info here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29)

The original attempt, modified to filter WARN & ERROR:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout, stderr

# configure stdout
# set the conversion pattern of stdout
# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.Target   = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMin=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMax=INFO

# configure stderr
# set the conversion pattern of stdout
# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold = WARN
log4j.appender.stderr.Target   = System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n
```

Comment: Are you sure the filter can be applied to the 1st appender like that?  I'm not having any luck using a .properties file

Comment: This solution works for me, maybe this should be marked as the solution rather than the answer provided by John B

Comment: Why does this solution work for some but not for others? (It doesn't work for me, the filter is not applied.)

Comment: Found the answer: it seems it is supported in properties file in 1.2.16 and 1.2.17 but not before that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730343/log4j-stringtomatch-in-property-file).

Answer (score 11):

1. instead of using .properties configuration you must use a .xml configuration.
2. In .xml config put an element named "filter" of type "org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter" and set its parameters `LevelMax` and `LevelMin`.

For example the following .xml configuration define two appenders: stdout, stderr. The stdout prints all logs that have a level less than or equal to INFO to stdout, and the stderr prints all logs with level greater than INFO to stderr.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Document    : log4j.xml
    Created on  : 13 Δεκέμβριος 2011, 3:55 μμ
    Author      : elitex
    Description : Purpose of the document follows.
-->
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stderr" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="warn" />
        <param name="target" value="System.err"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <param name="target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="info" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="debug"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

For more info look at: http://www.laliluna.de/articles/posts/log4j-tutorial.html

Answer (score 6):

another example using the `ThresholdFilter` markup from log4j2.

```
<Console name="ConsoleERR" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n"/>
    <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</Console>
```

See the [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is logback config which does exactly(!) what you asking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.err</target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="${LOGBACK_ROOT_LEVEL:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry, that also filters out trace and debug messages

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to NEUTRAL and adding filter for DEBUG should let it capture DEBUG as well. There is another built-in filter which requires [janino](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/janino/3.0.9) dependency:

```
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">      
        <evaluator> 
            <expression>
                   <![CDATA[ level > INFO ]]>
            </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
    </filter>
```