# Log4j custom configuration to separate log for each level - Playframework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework, log4j, playframework-1.x

I am trying to log some user data to log file whenever a request arrive with `log4j` in **Play! Framework 1.2.5**. I need to have 2 separated log file which will be used by different methods and classes. I would like to have my customized log files formatted as :

> **date with time - request running time and some string**

**First question** : Could you please show me a helpful tutorial or an answer? Because whatever I have done so far was useless.

**The second question** : How can I configure log4j to log for each level such as only log `ERROR` message on one file, while only print `INFO` and `WARN` message on other file. My `log4j.properties` file is below. I know the previleges  of message. But even I defined threshold why `ERROR`, `FATAL` or `WARN` messages also are written to info file?

```
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, JUSTINFO, JUSTERROR
log4j.logger = INFO

log4j.appender.JUSTINFO = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JUSTINFO.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JUSTINFO.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - [%X{processTime}] - %m%n
log4j.appender.JUSTINFO.File = log/info.log
log4j.appender.JUSTINFO.Threshold = INFO

log4j.appender.JUSTERROR = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JUSTERROR.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JUSTERROR.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - [%X{processTime}] - %m%n
log4j.appender.JUSTERROR.File =log/warn.log
log4j.appender.JUSTERROR.Threshold = ERROR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use NDC (Nested Diagnostic Context) or MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context). Below is an example calling the `Logger` on controller :

```java
public static StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

public static void request001() {
    sw.start(); // start timer
    // logic of processing the request
    ...
    sw.stop(); // stop timer
    // using MDC to put elapsed time in milisecond
    MDC.put("processTime", sw.getElapsedTime());
    Logger.info("this is request001"); 
}
```

And the `log4j.properties` example file should be like follow (using console appender):

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, loggerName
log4j.appender.loggerName = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.loggerName.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.loggerName.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} - [%X{processTime}] - %m
```

`%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}` is used to output the date while`%X{processTime}` is used to get the `processTime` value stored in MDC.

You can check the references here :

1. [Log4j 1.2 Manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
2. [`PatternLayout` JavaDoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)
3. [What is the difference between Log4j's NDC and MDC facilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134734/log4j-ndc-vs-mdc-difference)

---

#### Update

**Threshold** properties is represents the **minimum** Level/Priority accepted, not an absolute Level/Priority. So, your `JUSTINFO` logger should log logger that have priority starting from `INFO` or higher.

If you want to separate the logging message to exactly match the level (absolute level range filter), I think you should consider to replace the log4j.properties to log4j.xml (configuration using xml). I give you example :

```xml
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
   <!-- JUSTINFO logging -->
   <appender name="JUSTINFO" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="./info.log" />
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %t - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
      <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
         <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
         <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO" />
       </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- JUSTERROR logging -->
    <appender name="JUSTERROR" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="./error.log" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %t - %m%n"/>
       </layout>
       <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
          <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
          <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR" />
       </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- define root logger priority to ERROR -->
    <root>
       <level value="ERROR"/>
       <appender-ref ref="JUSTINFO"/>
       <appender-ref ref="JUSTERROR"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Here also a good reference for you :

1. [Why chose XML over properties files for Log4J configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256835/why-chose-xml-over-properties-files-for-log4j-configuration)
2. [How to set filter in the log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825072/how-to-set-filter-in-the-log4j-xml)

Comment: thank you for your answer. It worked. But it could not cover whole my problem. I need to write info message to a log file just for info and warn or any error message to another log file. I found an example of custom appender and when I put it in log4j.properties, I got classNotFound exception

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope it useful for you, friend. ;)

Comment: I am getting this warning when using log4j.xml. should I user a new appender and root for JUSTINFO as well?log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 16 and column 12
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,par
am*,rollingPolicy?,triggeringPolicy?,connectionSource?,layout?,filter*,appender-
ref*)".

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have tested it myself. Hope make you better understand. Good luck, friend ;)

Comment: Ahh . thank you my brother. you were too usefull for the logging process of my project :) thanks again.